# Ошибка при подсчете

Tags: java, android

Пробую находить процент от числа. Делаю это так: ввожу число, ввожу процент который нужно узнать, нажимаю на кнопку и получаю точное значение процента
Реализовываю это так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText1;
private EditText editText2;
private Button button1;
private TextView textView1;
private ImageButton imageButton1;

private String a;
private String b;
private String res;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    imageButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbut1);

    a = editText1.getText().toString();
    b = editText2.getText().toString();


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float dig;
            float per;
            float exit;

            dig = Float.parseFloat(a);
            per = Float.parseFloat(b);

            exit = dig * per / 100;

            res = Float.toString(exit);

        }
    });

}
}
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку, пишет `"В приложении произошла ошибка"`
Подскажите, что я не правильно сделал?

Comment: Какая именно ошибка? Приведите стектрейс

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы думаете что получив в методе `onCreate` значения из текстовых полей, и после ввода пользователем каких то значений туда они волшебным образом окажутся в этих переменных, то нет, я вас огорчу, такого не будет. Хотя и нет стектрейса, но думаю что ошибка возникает из-за попытки преобразовать пустую строку к `Float`.

Сделайте так:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        float dig;
        float per;
        float exit;

        String a = editText1.getText().toString();
        String b = editText2.getText().toString();

        if(!a.isEmpty() && !b.isEmpty()) {
            dig = Float.parseFloat(a);
            per = Float.parseFloat(b);
            exit = dig * per / 100;
            res = Float.toString(exit);
        }
    }
});
```